# Invalid IL Code - F#

Tags: f#, mono

I am new to F#, and I am trying to write a function that calculates a powerset.

I am getting an error from Mono (running this on a Mac) that is below.

For example, I would pass calcPowerSet ([1;2;3], []) to start the function. Any ideas on how to solve the issue?

```
System.InvalidProgramException: Invalid IL code in FSI_0010:calcPowerSet (Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.List`1,Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.List`1): IL_005d: stind.r4  


  at FSI_0010.calcPowerSet[Int32] (Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.List`1 _arg1_0, Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.List`1 _arg1_1) [0x00000] 
  at .$FSI_0011._main () [0x00000] 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke (object,object[],System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00000] 
stopped due to error
```

Code:

```
let rec calcPowerSet = function
 | ([], []) -> [[]]
 | ((head::tail), (cHead::cTail)) -> 
  calcPowerSet (tail, (cHead::cTail)) @ calcPowerSet (tail, (head::cHead::cTail))
 | ((head::tail), []) -> 
  calcPowerSet (tail, []) @ calcPowerSet (tail, [head])
 | ([], collect) -> [collect];;
```

Comment: Which version of F#?  (e.g. 1.9.6.2)

Comment: FYI - On 1.9.6.2 on Windows, your function works as expected.

Comment: Interesting. I am using F# 1.9.4.19

I will try on a windows machine. Could this be a mono implementation issue?

Comment: It might be a mono issue or it might be an F# issue; with more data can probably nail it down.

Comment: Which version of mono are you using?

Comment: I am running 2.4 Mono. I have included the version information below.

DevoJunior:FSharp-1.9.4.19 pdhharris$ mono --version
Mono JIT compiler version 2.4 (tarball Fri Mar 13 09:25:35 MDT 2009)
Copyright (C) 2002-2008 Novell, Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
 TLS:           normal
 GC:            Included Boehm (with typed GC)
 SIGSEGV:       normal
 Notification:  Thread + polling
 Architecture:  x86
 Disabled:      none

Comment: FYI: I get the same result under F# v1.9.6.2, Mono v2.4 on my Macbook Pro.

Comment: I tested on a windows machine, and it did return a result. The result however wasn't the powerset, and changing "collect" to "(cHead::cTail)" resolved that. Anyhow, it does seem to be just related to the mac (using the changed code resulted in the same issue). Johan, I haven't had a chance to try out your code, but I will and then I get back with everyone.

Comment: I am experiencing the same exception in my code.  Unfortunately I cant provide the full stack trace, and code in the comment.
<output>
System.InvalidProgramException: Invalid IL code in FSI_0003.Gol:count<bool> (Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FastFunc`2<bool, bool>,Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.List`1<bool>): IL_008a: conv.ovf.u2.un
</output>

Comment: Here is my function: http://pastebin.com/m6ec637a7
I am using Mono 2.4, and fsi 1.9.6.2 on a MacBook Pro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no idea why it doesn't work (I got the same result) but if you rewrite it as:

```
let calcPowerSet =
   let rec innerCalc = 
      function
      | ([], []) -> [[]]
      | ((head::tail), (cHead::cTail)) -> 
         innerCalc (tail, (cHead::cTail)) @ innerCalc (tail, (head::cHead::cTail))
      | ((head::tail), []) -> 
         innerCalc (tail, []) @ innerCalc (tail, [head])
      | ([], collect) -> [collect]
   innerCalc
```

it seems to work fine under Mac (intel) with Mono 2.4 and F# 1.9.6.2

Comment: (see my comments in the question's comments)
I change my function by using an inner function like Johan's method and it works.  See the changes here: http://pastebin.com/m6ec637a7

Answer (score 2):

FYI, turns out the F# team is aware of this bug, it is a bug in Mono 2.4 that Mono team is aware of (dunno if has been fixed yet).

Comment: Good to know - is there a bug forum for that so I can follow it's progress?

Comment: Still about F# and mono bugs, I remember a post on the Flying Frog Consultancy blog which proved that - as of version 2.2 of mono - tail recursion wasn't adequately supported yet and resulted in leaked memory (don't know how's the situation now as I don't do mono).